# Is there a way to return the names of rows with specific average column values?

Tags: r, subset

I am using the data set `Income_Democracy.dta`
I am trying to find the name of countries that have an average `dem_ind` value greater than `0.95`.

I figure I need to subset the countries, find the average, and return that as a new data set, but I can't figure out how to do it without the specific country names. I've fiddled with the which and subset functions but I'm only new to `R` and need help.
For the specific countries I know you can do

`mean(subset(incdem$dem_ind, incdem$country =="Australia"))`

but I'm unsure how to generalise.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grouped by 'country', get the `mean` of 'dem_ind', `filter` the rows where the 'mean' column value is greater than 0.95 and `pull` the 'country' column as a `vector`

```
library(dplyr)
incdem %>%
    group_by(country) %>%
    summarise(Avg = mean(dem_ind, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    filter(Avg > 0.95) %>%
    pull(country)
```

---

Or another option is

```
names(which(sapply(split(incdem$dem_ind, incdem$country), mean, 
        na.rm = TRUE) > 0.95))
```

---

If it is a range of values

```
names(which(sapply(split(incdem$dem_ind, incdem$country), function(x) {
          avg <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
          avg > 0.2 & avg < 0.8})))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, is there a way to apply this so that it looks for a range of values e.g. between 0.2 and 0.8?

Comment: @user17237061 does it work for you?

Comment: gives error message "Error in Match.fun(FUN): argument FUN is missing, with no default"

Comment: @user17237061 sorry, the `split` was missing a `)`